# Bluestacks as a smarter apk testing tool - installing app from harddisk

Tags: android, installation, bluestacks

What conditions need to be met for an apk app exported from, say eclipse, to install from hard disk into Bluestacks?

Answer (score 0):

### To install your own program's .APK

By your mention of `"say eclipse"` I am going to assume you are working in Eclipse. Just run the BlueStacks App Player and it will show up in your list of running devices.

`Windows -> Show View -> Other -> Devices` (or the list the automatically shows up at run)

Use run (or run with debugging) to deploy your .APK to BlueStacks. It's just like any other emulator, really.

### To install any other .APK (not so much a programming question)

The most convenient way is to use the application `HD-ApkHandler.exe` the comes pre-installed in the BlueStacks folder.

Comment: [google chrome: no formatting in comment?!]
I get to show view, double click devices and a lower pane opens with a list of just one emulator 5554 which when expanded shows many lines of strange data:
com.bluestacks.bstfolder
com.bluestacks.home
etc

What do they mean? 

I have a hunch it is just the emulator that I have been using so far.

 a mention of bluestacks emulator.

When I doubleclick the apk file in windows bluestacks takes over and tries to instal, it ends up with "install parse failed no certificates". Do I need to add some android specific data before running a test in eclipse?